# WAL archiving w/ streaming replication

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, write-ahead-logging

I'm running postgresql 9.3. I've currently got WAL archiving configured, but I'm doubting it's utility based on my configuration. On the master, I've got archive_command set to

> rsync -az --ignore-existing %p postgres@slave_replica:/wal_archive

and on the slave replica, I've got restore_command set to

> cp /wal_archive/%f %p || exit 0

If the slave server goes offline, it won't be able to receive the WAL files, and then when it comes back up, won't have what it needs.

Should I instead effectively reverse those two commands: archive the WALs locally on the master, and have slave replica rsync them from the master server? Or should I have the master archive the WALs both to a local directory and rsync them to the slave?

Comment: You should upgrade to PostgreSQL 10, and use streaming replication. PostgreSQL 9.3 is EOL.

Comment: I'm sure we will, but EOL for 9.3 isn't until September 2018, and we've got a big bureaucratic CM process that moves slow. In the meantime, we need our current system to work. So any advice on addressing my original question in 9.3?

Comment: I don't believe `postgres@:/wal_archive` is legal syntax for rsync.  In my hands it always returns an error code, meaning that postgres will never remove the file from pg_xlog.

Comment: @jjanes: Sorry, that was a typo in the post, not in the config file. I've fixed the post.

Answer (score 2):

If the slave server is offline, the `rsync` in the `archive_command` should fail (exit with a non-zero exit value), which means the master will keep retrying it until it succeeds.  It will not remove a pg_xlog file until it is successfully archived.  So it will still be there when the slave comes back on online.

Also, the `|| exit 0` at the end of your restore command is just wrong.  `PostgreSQL` will ask for files which do not exist, and has to be told they don't exist (by returning a non-zero exit code)

Comment: That's why I shouldn't read documentation when I'm tired. I misunderstood what it said about restore_command exit codes. Thanks. I've removed the `|| exit 0`.

Comment: So other than the `|| exit 0`, does my configuration look like it will work when the slave goes offline for a few hours?

Answer (score 0):

Restore, afaik, tries to load *all WAL logs* at the directory you're pointing it to  From the docs,

> The standby server can read WAL from a WAL archive (see restore_command) or directly from the master over a TCP connection (streaming replication). [...] At startup, the standby begins by restoring all WAL available in the archive location

If you need *warm* standby under the archive/restore mode, I believe you want to look at the utility [`pg_standby`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgstandby.html)